# How to map a grid to a sphere

Tags: materials, uv

I am trying to achieve this effect.

[image]

https://images.app.goo.gl/mJzaTvwhLha3MiVt6

I am only interested in the outer shell.

I want to be able to create my own grid with different colors and angles. Maybe add randomness to how the points connect. How can I create a network style grid on a sphere?

Thank you.

Comment: you could create an Ico Sphere, then give it a Wireframe modifier, then a Particle > Hair, with a little sphere as object. I'm looking how to make the little sphere size unique though...

Comment: oh ok you need to put the Particle System above the Wireframe modifier so that all the hairs have the same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered somewhere but I don't know where, so what you should do is:

- Create an icosphere and a small sphere. Give your icosphere a *Particle System* > *Hair*. Enable the *Advanced* option. In *Render*, enable *Object* and choose the little sphere as *Dupli Object*. In *Emission* give it the number of vertices your icosphere has and choose *Emit From* > *Verts*, deactivate *Random*, set the *Hair Length* value.

[image]

- Give your icosphere a *Wireframe* modifier. Choose the *Thickness* you want. You'll have to choose an *Emission* shader as material.

[image]